# Unmount the directory which is mounted by sshfs in Mac

Tags: macos, sshfs, umount

I've installed `OSXFUSE` in my mac and used `sshfs` to mount a remote directory. Now I would like to unmount it, but can't find the way. 
My OS is OSX 10.8 Mountain. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: This question belongs to SuperUser, although there's already [ssh - How to avoid sshfs freezing? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/443878/how-to-avoid-sshfs-freezing) there

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Don't use `umount`.

Use

```
fusermount -u PATH
```

Comment: This answer came from @peterdemin in the comment for [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16674890/393280).

Comment: fusermount is not found on OS10.8

Comment: Use `umount`, as the docs say (pointed to by the answer of @opsmason).

Comment: the  <umount> option works fine under  Mac System Version: OS X 10.10.3   even without sudo

Comment: Wasn't getting `umount` to work initially because I thought it was `unmount`—there's no `n`!

Comment: macOS 10.13.4: None of these options have worked for me. "umount: gave me "Resource busy -- try 'diskutil unmount'", and that cmd gave me: "Unmount failed for <path>". Edit: BUT  umount -f <path> did work!

Comment: This answer is blatantly wrong, [fusermount **does not exist** in the macOS version of sshfs](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ#48-how-should-i-unmount-my-fuse-for-os-x-file-system-i-cannot-find-the-fusermount-program-anywhere) (sshfs FAQ).

Comment: Works on macOS 10.14.2.

Comment: `umount -f /path/to/folder` if receiving `Resource busy` with `umount` and `failed` with `diskutil` (Catalina `10.15.2`).

Comment: Why? What's wrong with umount. This should not have so many upvotes without a reason!

Answer (score 222):

Try this:

```
umount -f <absolute pathname to the mount point>
```

Example:

```
umount -f /Users/plummie/Documents/stanford
```

If that doesn't work, try the same command as root:

```
sudo umount -f ...
```

Comment: Using umount -f left me with broken directory giving error: "bash: cd: directory-name: Transport endpoint is not connected"

Comment: Note for future use: the command above works just fine on Mavericks. Also, an absolute path isn't necessary.

Comment: Fine on OS X 10.10.2 and homebrew

Comment: @peterdemin - that link doesn't seem to go to what you think it should.

Comment: Fine on OSX 10.10.4 using `umount -f /Users/me/Documents/there` without sudo

Comment: Works on 10.12.1 Sierra with `umount -f ~/relative-path`

Comment: Fails on 10.13 with error: `Operation not permitted`. Have to use sudo even for a folder in my homedir.

Comment: For me, it did not work when I used a relative path (cd ~/Desktop; umount -f rambo). It said the path was not currently mounted. It worked with a user relative path (umount -f ~/Desktop/rambo)

Comment: This was the only command that worked after my /Volumes/mymount mount point went sour, giving the error message "rm: /Volumes/mymount Device not configured" when trying to sudo rm it.

Comment: `umount -f <path>` worked on OSX 10.15.5

Answer (score 50):

```
sudo diskutil unmount force PATH
```

Works every time :)
Notice the `force` flag

Comment: Indeed it works every time . Key is the force option :-)

For instance : 

I  was getting the following error with umount  
mount_osxfuse: mount point /Users/mount/root is itself on a OSXFUSE volume
diskutil

Comment: The only thing that actually worked. It's a puzzle to me that `sodo umount -f` didn't work here... I had zombie volumes from `sshfs`

Answer (score 18):

At least in 10.11 (El Capitan), the man page for umount indicates:

> Due to the complex and interwoven nature of Mac OS X, umount may fail
>   often.  It is recommended that diskutil(1) (as in, "diskutil unmount
>   /mnt") be used instead.

This approach (e.g., "diskutil umount *path/to/mount/point*") allows me to unmount sshfs-mounted content, and does not require sudo.  (And I believe that it should work back through at least 10.8.)

Comment: A broken pipe would sometimes leave the volume in a very bad state. In these cases, only ```diskutil unmount force /path/to/mountpoint``` would help for me.

Comment: Incidentally, this only works for me if I use `diskutil umount force ...`. Other methods [here](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/45) as well.

Answer (score 13):

use `ps aux | grep sshfs` to find the PID of sshfs (It will be the number next to the username)

Then `kill -9 $PID`, if the other solutions don't work

Comment: Works on OS X 10.11.0, after suspending it and moving to a different network (leaving the mount point with Input/Output errors). umount didn't work, fusermount not installed

Comment: This worked for me when I ran into a situation where many appps/processes were beachballing/“stuck“-status-in-top/“U”-status-in-ps.  Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me:

```
hdiutil detach <path to sshfs mount>
```

Example:

```
hdiutil detach /Users/user1/sshfs
```

One can also locate the volume created by sshfs in Finder, right-click, and select Eject.  Which is, to the best of my knowledge, the GUI version of the above command.

Comment: This is something that worked for me without a hitch on macOS Sierra. I suspected this would work flawlessly because on Gui I press the eject button this would be the thing that was happening.

Comment: Works perfectly on **macOS Sierra**.

Comment: Works for me on High Sierrra when the other approaches didn't, but had to add the "-force" option: e.g  "hdiutil detach /Users/user1/sshfs -force"

Answer (score 5):

If your problem is that you mounted a network drive with SSHFS, but the ssh connection got cut and you simply cannot remount it because of an error like `mount_osxfuse: mount point /Users/your_user/mount_folder is itself on a OSXFUSE volume`, the github user [theunsa](https://github.com/theunsa) found [a solution](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/45#issuecomment-21943107) that works for me. Quoting his answer:

---

My current workaround is to:

Find the culprit sshfs process:

```
$ pgrep -lf sshfs
```

Kill it:

```
$ kill -9 <pid_of_sshfs_process>
```

sudo force unmount the "unavailable" directory:

```
$ sudo umount -f <mounted_dir>
```

Remount the now "available" directory with sshfs ... and then tomorrow morning go back to step 1.

Answer (score 4):

Just as reference let me quote the [osxfuse FAQ](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ#48-how-should-i-unmount-my-fuse-for-os-x-file-system-i-cannot-find-the-fusermount-program-anywhere)

> 4.8. How should I unmount my "FUSE for OS X" file system? I cannot find the fusermount program anywhere.
>
> Just use the standard umount command in OS X. You do not need the Linux-specific fusermount with "FUSE for OS X".

As mentioned above, either `diskutil unmount` or `umount` should work

Comment: Today, homebrew suggests "macFuse" (deciding to stop offering osxfuse) -- using `umount` in my OS X still works with "macFuse" just fine (MacOS 13.4.1)

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Mac OS Mojave), the key is to use the **full path**

`$umount -f /Volumnes/fullpath/folder`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a problems with `fusermount` command you can kill the process :

> ps -ax | grep "sshfs"

Comment: Or even: killall sshfs

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference I found this worked for me.

diskutil unmount /path/to/directory/

When I used the umount command I got an error that recommended this diskutil command.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this from finder. Simply navigate to the directory above where the mount is and hit the eject icon over the mounted folder, which will have SSHFS in the name (in the finder). A shortcut to open a folder in the finder from the terminal is

`open .`

which will open up the current directory in a new finder window. Replace "." with your directory of choice.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to kill all mounted sshfs connections you can use this. I tried it with ubuntu.

```
ps -ef | grep "sshfs" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

I added it to bash_aliases